# Уместны ли ссылки в подписи?

Tags: поддержка, ответы, профиль-участника

Есть некоторый участник, добавляющий в каждый ответ ссылку на свой сайт.

Уместно ли подобное? Нашёл только одно обсуждение, в котором затрагивается данный вопрос, поэтому решил уточнить ещё раз.

Насколько я понимаю - не приветствуются, т.к. несут "информационный шум" и их нужно/можно удалять, если увидишь. Верно?

Comment: если это просто ссылка на сайт. можно рассматривать это как спам. Если ссылка на более развернутый ответ - то ок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как это часто бывает, ответ уже есть на MSE: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way) и даже помечен меткой [faq].

Основной посыл в следующем:

- Ответ должен быть полезен и без наличия ссылки
- Ответ содержит несколько более краткий пересказ того, что можно найти по ссылке (как вариант, отсутствуют примеры или некоторые нюансы)
- Указано авторство текста, приведенного в ссылке
- Присутствует информация о причинах наличия ссылки, чтобы читатель мог оценить, стоит ли по ней переходить или ему достаточно самого ответа

Таким образом, обычное упоминание личного сайта в качестве подписи к ответу не приветствуется и может быть расценено как спам, если ссылка не удовлетворяет приведённым выше критериям. При этом, наличие ссылки на личный сайт вполне допустимо на странице профиля участника, там даже поле есть соответствующее.